# Gke - kubernetes / how to ensure deployment isolation on a given node

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-deployment

A little bit lost in between nodeselector, affinity / anti affinity; taints

What i'd be interested in would be to ensure that a single pod/deployement would run on a given node, not anywhere else. and that this node would not receive any other pod than the specified one

Given the options above (if there are any else), what would be the most concise way to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some label only on one node.
or
You can create a new node-pool with one node.(I would prefer this since this can work well with autoscaling, set min, max nodes to 1)

Create a deployment with one replica and affinity equal to this node.

To limit running just this pod on node:
1) You can add resource limit equal to node's resource value, so that no other pods are scheduled on this node.
or
2) Use some default affinity for all the other pods
or
3) Use [node-isolation-restriction](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-isolation-restriction) to restrict which pods can be scheduled on this node. Haven't tried this myself yet

Comment: yep it's basically that, I will create a node pool with one node, then I'd look into running a single pod on this given node pool. I've haven't looked into this one yet "...add resource limit equal to node's resource value, so that no other pods are scheduled on this node", how do you do so ?

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/

Read about this in docs. Comment here if you need help :)

Comment: A bit curious, why do you need just one pod on a node though ?

Comment: it is more about finding the best way to isolate hosted third parties. Rather a user, in a given node pool. That could end up with numerous pods on numerous nodes; but I personnally find it messy to let kubernetes do the job by itself in this context

Comment: That means you will add node for each third party application/service ?

Comment: this is what I mean yep (on gcloud micro or small are cheap). it kinda defeats the point of using kub, but as it is possible with the given options, we're considering it